# Azure Functions TimerTrigger Restarted after hours of running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

My Azure Function App (TimerTrigger) restarted after hours of running. How to prevent my Function App from stop running before it finishes? It is running on App Service plan.

```
Always On = True
```

[image]

This image shows what happens before it stopped running.

Comment: Can you try going to the Function UI and clicking the Refresh button? This is to check if it triggers correctly.

Comment: Do you have consumption plan or app service plan?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT it is a app service plan. And the triggers are correct. But the host got restarted in the middel of a running function.